# HTML table - Change the width of a single cell in a column

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is there a more elegant solution to achieve the same effect as this?

[image: HTML table with different cell widths in one column]

The code I've got so far is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      table { border-collapse: collapse; }
      td { border: solid 1px; }
      td.nest { padding: 0px; }
      td.nest table td { border-width: 0px 1px; }
      td.nest table td:first-child { border-left: none; }
      td.nest table td:last-child { border-right: none; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 3em;"/>
        <col style="width: 6em;"/>
        <col style="width: 9em;"/>
      </colgroup>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><!-- Somehow get rid of the nested table and keep just the tds -->
        <td class="nest" colspan="3">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 4em;">1</td>
              <td style="width: 6em;">2</td>
              <td style="width: 8em;">3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only way I can get this working so far is to nest another table inside the first. I don't like it much because ideally I only want one table and there's a lot of extra CSS to match the borders of the first table without adding to the cell (`colspan="3"`) size. I want to be able to replace the nested table with just a normal `<tr>` with three `<td>`s in it.

The only other way I've found to change the width of one cell without affecting the other cells in the column is with `position: absolute;` but then the next cell in the row is shifted to the left by the width of the adjusted cell, so that doesn't work fully. It's also too hard to get the widths just right.

So, is there any way to get the same effect using just one table, no extra `<div>`s, etc. and just simple CSS? This example should have only one `<table>`, nine `<td>`s and no `colspan=`s. I'm looking for a pure CSS solution if one exists. It should be able to cope with any arbitrary widths as long as they add up to the original width.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible without subtables.
What you are trying to do is against the idea of tabular data presentation. 
If you don't want a table, don't use a table.

You could however put your data into divs with  `style="display: table-cell;"`.

On a second thought, you could use colspan in all 3 rows.
So your table actually looks like this:

[image: Colspan]

```
 <col style="width: 3em;"/>
 <col style="width: 1em;"/>
 <col style="width: 5em;"/>
 <col style="width: 1em;"/>
 <col style="width: 8em;"/>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table Test</title>
      <style type="text/css">
          table {
              border-collapse: collapse;
          }

          td {
              border: solid 1px;
          }

        td.nest {
            padding: 0px;
        }

        td.nest table td {
            border-width: 0px 1px;
        }

        td.nest table td:first-child {
            border-left: none;
        }

        td.nest table td:last-child {
            border-right: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table >
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 3em;" />
            <col style="width: 1em;" />
            <col style="width: 5em;" />
            <col style="width: 1em;" />
            <col style="width: 8em;" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td colspan="2">2</td>
            <td colspan="2">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">1</td>
            <td colspan="2">2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td colspan="2">2</td>
            <td colspan="2">3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I asked for no `colspan`s because the table could be huge; I'd need a lot of columns and calculations to make it come out right. Imagine doing this on a table 10 columns by 100 rows. I have no idea in advance the widths of each cell, only the default widths which are allowed to be overridden. Another advantage is that I can write the table out in one pass instead of getting every row, calculating the number of columns I need and `colspan`ing all the cells. I could even used `table-layout: fixed;`.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**...but you'll have to use some CSS trickery to 'fake' it.

What the below does is use psuedo elements for the inner borders, offsetting them as appropriate for the middle row.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/46rmP/1/)

CSS

```
  table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      table-layout:fixed;
  }
  td {
      border: solid 1px;
      border-width:1px 0px 1px 0px;
      width:33%;
      position:relative;
  }
  td:nth-child(1) {
      border-left:solid 1px;
  }
  td.nest {
      padding: 0px;
  }
  td.nest table td {
      border-width: 0px 1px;
  }
  td.nest table td:first-child {
      border-left: none;
  }
  td.nest table td:last-child {
      border-right: none;
  }
  td:after {
      content:'';
      position:absolute;
      right:0;
      border-right:1px solid black;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
  }
  tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-of-type(1):after, tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-of-type(2):after {
      right:-20px;
  }
  tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-of-type(2), tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-of-type(3) {
      padding-left:25px;
  }
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 3em;" />
        <col style="width: 6em;" />
        <col style="width: 9em;" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm still trying to understand how your code works but that's brilliant! I took out your `width:33%;` and I got the same output as my code!

Comment: `:after` is a pseudo element you can style, it appears 'after' the DOM element the CSS is applied to (also; `:before`), styling this allows you to fake borders

Comment: I've played with your solution and it only fiddles with the appearance of the cell borders, the cell itself remains the same size but with more padding, reducing the usable space for the text. I'd like it to actually change the cell size too (i.e. move the cell boundary either to the left or the right).

Comment: @CJDennis - not sure I follow: http://jsfiddle.net/46rmP/2/ - you may want to post as a new question to get more coverage

Answer (score 0):

You can use next html for example :

```
<table style="width: 300px;">
    <colgroup>
        <col span="1" style="width: auto;">
        <col span="1" style="width: auto;">
        <col span="1" style="width: auto;">
        <col span="1" style="width: auto;">
        <col span="1" style="width: auto;">
        <col span="1" style="width: auto;">
        <col span="1" style="width: auto;">
        <col span="1" style="width: auto;">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>      
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the unit % instead of pixels its work for me.

```
width:30%
```