# How to move specific td elements in a table

Tags: css, html-table

I have the the following [image: following] table structure, but I want to change it to this[image: this] table structure.

I have looked at posts on SO and other places but have not been able to find a solution. Is this possible using css? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757695/html-table-change-the-width-of-a-single-cell-in-a-column) SO posts is the closest I have found but it still does not work as needed.

Can someone please guide me on how to approach this?

Comment: this is not how table works .. unless you play with colspan/rowspan and hide borders, etc but it will be a pain

Comment: @TemaniAfif, what will be a better approach for this? Just using divs?

Comment: yes, simple div and you can easily control width of each one like you want

Comment: @Hamadkhan can you simply show us a simple code where margin on td works? .. you insist on this so please show us a code where you solve this with margin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one table per row as a workaround, with CSS for the borders as shown below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: none;
}

table:last-of-type td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test Test Test Test Test Test</td>
    <td>Test Test</td>
    <td>Test Test Test Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test Test</td>
    <td>Test Test Test Test</td>
    <td>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using flex you can do this with `align-items: stretch;`

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#container div {
  height: 30px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style="width: 80px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 35px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 35px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 50px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 50px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 50px;"></div>
</div>
```